# Pacman: Target can be found for reinstall, but not for removal

Tags: manjaro, pacman, aur

I'm using the Manjaro i3 setup, which comes with the palemoon browser. I however really don't have any need for this, so I'd like to uninstall.

When I run `pacman -Rns palemoon`, I get `error: target not found: palemoon`. Odd, but seeing as how it was bundled with the distro I installed from it's not completely outside the realm of possibility that the binary was just added to the system rather than being installed from a package manager.

Oddly enough though, if I run `pacman -S palemoon` I'm given the standard reinstall prompt. How can this be? Target found on reinstall, but not on removal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed 'palemoon-bin' while running an update. Apparently that was the key. Didn't expect that.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and congratulations on finding the solution yourself. Would you mind expanding the post with more explanation so that it will also help someone who found your post while googling?

Comment: Not sure there's really more to add. I ran an update (`pacman -Syu`), saw `palemoon-bin` in the list and then tried that. It worked.